# How to distribute my WebView2 WPF app by Fixed Version distribution mode?

Tags: c#, wpf, microsoft-edge, webview2, microsoft-edge-chromium

I want to distribute my wpf app with fixed version WebView2, here is my XAML code:

XAML:

```
<wv2:WebView2 x:Name="webView" vm:ReceiverViewModel.PreviewData="{Binding MyData}">
    <wv2:WebView2.CreationProperties>
        <wv2:CoreWebView2CreationProperties>
            <wv2:CoreWebView2CreationProperties.BrowserExecutableFolder>
                Microsoft.WebView2.FixedVersionRuntime.87.0.664.8.x86\\EBWebView\\x86
            </wv2:CoreWebView2CreationProperties.BrowserExecutableFolder>
        </wv2:CoreWebView2CreationProperties>
    </wv2:WebView2.CreationProperties>
</wv2:WebView2>
```

C#:

```
public Receiver()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    webView.Source = new Uri(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Receiver.html");
}
```

It doesn't work. Is `BrowserExecutableFolder` set correctly?

Comment: You can refer to [this doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution#fixed-version-distribution-mode) about how to use Fixed Version distribution mode. The `BrowserExecutableFolder` should refer to the path of the Fixed Version binaries where you download from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) and decompressed. You can also refer to [this thread](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/578) which points out that *You must specify the environment before the WebView2 Source property takes effect*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Fixed Version deployment, when providing a browserExecutableFolder you must specify the path to the folder containing msedgewebview.exe. In the above you likely want to specify `Microsoft.WebView2.FixedVersionRuntime.87.0.664.8.x86` not the EBWebView\x86 subfolder.

Comment: Can we get a working example on the github, couldn't find and example on the readme.md @David ?

Comment: Good suggestion. That's missing from our samples repo. I'll open a task for that.